# Django: exclude User list from all Users

Tags: python, django, django-models

I just started working with Django, at the moment I am working on a method in a model. My question is as follows: How can I exclude a list of users from user instances? With this method:

```
def get_other_users(self):
    all = User.objects.all()
    return User.objects.exclude(self.get_shift_users())
```

I get the error: AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'split'

Code for get_shift_users:

```
@property
def get_shift_users(self):
    return User.objects.filter(assign__shift=self)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to implement it by writing a symmetrical query, like:

```
def get_other_users(self):
    return User.objects.exclude(assign__shift=self)
```