# Django: exclude User list from all Users

Tags: python, django, django-models

I asked a similar question today ([Django: exclude User list from all Users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29055516/django-exclude-user-list-from-all-users) ), the sollution was to write a symmetrical query. Since I changed my models with a many-to-many relation, this solution isn't valid anymore.

How can I exclude a list of users from user instances? With this method:

```
class Shift(models.Model):
    shift_location = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User)

    def get_shift_users(self):
        return self.users.all()

    def get_other_users(self):
        return User.objects.all().exclude(self.users.all())
```

I get the error: AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'split'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `in` operator:

```
User.objects.exclude(id__in=self.users.all())
```

By using an unevaluated queryset (`self.users.all()`), it is transformed in a subquery, so the result will be fetched in a single query.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
User.objects.all().exclude(id__in=[u.id for u in self.users.all()])
```